# ASP.NET Core 7 MVC, EF Core, SQL Server : DbContext connection issue upgrade from .NET 4.8 EF6

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-6, dbcontext, .net-7.0

I am having problems with a SQL Server connection while upgrading an ASP.NET 4.8 MVC application to an ASP.NET Core 7 MVC application.

When a controller references the `MainDbContext`, it's value is null. The connection string worked fine with `Microsoft.EntityFramework.SqlServer` but does not seem to work with `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` (even with the addition of `TrustServerCertificate=True`).

Here is the structure. The `TestDbConnection` was added later to isolate the issue specific to the SQL Server rather than the code.

`launchSettings.json` with connection strings:

```json
{
    "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Information",
            "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
        }
    },
    "AllowedHosts": "*",
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "TestDbConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=TestDb;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true",
        "MainDbConnection": "data source=MyServer;initial catalog=MainDb;persist security info=True;user id=sa;password=***;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework;TrustServerCertificate=True"
    }
}
```

`program.cs` with dependency injection

```csharp
...

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("MainDbConnection");

builder.Services.AddDbContext<MainDbContext>(options =>
   options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("TestDbConnection");

builder.Services.AddDbContext<TestDbContext>(options =>
   options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
...
```

`MainDbContext.cs` inherited DbContext class:

```csharp
public class MainDbContext: DbContext
{
    public MainDbContext(DbContextOptions<MainDbContext> options) : base(options){}

    public virtual DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Client>().ToTable("Client");
    }
}
```

Controller using `MainDbContext` connection:

```csharp
...

private readonly MainDbContext db; // returns null

public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    var tmpList = await db.Clients.ToListAsync() // NullReferenceException

    return View(tmpList);
}
...
```

In order to get some kind of feedback for why the service injection was quietly failing, I made a `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` connection in a controller to try and `catch` some info in case there was more to it than a `DbContext` issue.

The `catch` returned the error `The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted`, so I set the trust property `TrustServerCertificate=True`.

After that, the `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` was successful.

```csharp
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;

...
using (var conn = new SqlConnection("data source=MyServer;initial catalog=MainDb;persist security info=True;user id=sa;password=***;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework;TrustServerCertificate=True"))
{
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
                       
        try
        {
            string queryString = "SELECT * FROM Client";

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, conn))
            {
                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}", reader[0])); 
                    // successful output...
                    // 1
                    // 2
                    // 3
                    // etc.
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Could not retrieve Clients");
            Debug.WriteLine("  Exception: " + ex.Message);
            Debug.WriteLine("    Inner Exception: " + ex.InnerException);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Could Not Open Database");
        Debug.WriteLine("  Exception: " + ex.Message);
        Debug.WriteLine("    Inner Exception: " + ex.InnerException);
    }
}
```

The trust property `TrustServerCertificate=True` was then set in `MainDbConnection` and `MainDbContext` was tested again.

The service injection still returned null.

I was then wondering if there would be a problem connecting to my localdb using the `DbContext` class, so I duplicated the client table from the SQL Server and put it in a localdb.

Then placed the connection string in the `launchSettings.json` and created a new `TestDbContext`.

`TestDbContext.cs` inherited DbContext class:

```csharp
...

public class TestDbContext: DbContext
{
    public TestDbContext(DbContextOptions<TestDbContext> options) : base(options) 
    {}

    public virtual DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Client>().ToTable("Client");
    }
}
```

Made the call from the new test controller.

Success.

Controller using TestDbContext connection

```csharp
...

private readonly TestDbContext db; // success

public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
  var tmpList = await db.Clients.ToListAsync() // success

  return View(tmpList);
}

...
```

When researching .NET CORE EF6 connection string problems, it seems that the blanket response is to set `encrypt=false` and/or `TrustServerCertificate=True`, the latter which I used for the successful connection using `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`. However, after the addition of `TrustServerCertificate=True` in the launchSettings.json for the `MainDbContext`, it still did not work.

1. What is breaking when using the connection string with `DbContext` vs `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`?
2. Is there a way to produce error messages in the service injection?

Comment: looks llike it you are not passing db context to your controller. private readonly MainDbContext db; db is not initialized, can you show a code where db is initialized in your controller, if you don't have it, you need to do it.

Comment: It is in the section Controller using MainDbContext connection:. This is where I realized that the service injection was not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When a controller references the MainDbContext, it's value is null.
> The connection string worked fine with
> Microsoft.EntityFramework.SqlServer but does not seem to work with
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer (even with the addition of
> TrustServerCertificate=True).

Based on your shared code snippet and description, few inconsistencies has been found which causing the null data or unexpected output.

Program.cs:

First and most important point is your program.cs where you have set a single variable and switching them for both context. This is mainly causing the second context not working. Becuase its would always works for first initialized dbcontext. So instead of that you should use as following:

```cs
var connectionMainDbConnection = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("MainDbConnection");

builder.Services.AddDbContext<MainDbContext>(options =>
   options.UseSqlServer(connectionMainDbConnection));

var connectionTestDbConnection = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("TestDbConnection");

builder.Services.AddDbContext<TestDbContext>(options =>
   options.UseSqlServer(connectionTestDbConnection));
```

**Note:** Use separate variable for both connetion string.

Appsettings.json:

Another crucial point is that, your appsettings.json for MainDbConnection has incorrect attribute which is `App=EntityFramework;`. Unlike asp.net classic app in .NET 7 we don't need to specify this. Instead of that, your appsettings.json should be as following:

[image]

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "TestDbConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\ProjectModels;Database=TestDb;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true",
    "MainDbConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\ProjectModels;Database=MainDb;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  }
```

DbContext Constructor:

While initiating dbContext within the controller, you should pass the dbContext instance through the controller constructor which is not seen within your code snippet. Your controller should be as following:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
       
        private readonly MainDbContext _mainDbContext;
        private readonly TestDbContext _testDbContext;
        public HomeController(MainDbContext mainDbContext, TestDbContext testDbContext)
        {
            _mainDbContext = mainDbContext;
            _testDbContext = testDbContext;
        }
       
        public IActionResult GetClientFromMainDbContext()
        {

            List<string> listData = new List<string>();
            using (var conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(localdb)\\ProjectModels;Initial Catalog=MainDb;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"))
            {
                try
                {
                    conn.Open();

                    try
                    {
                       
                        string queryString = "SELECT * FROM Client";

                        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, conn))
                        {
                            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}", reader[0]));

                                string Name = reader.GetString(1);
                                string Description = reader.GetString(2);
                                listData.Add(Name);
                                listData.Add(Description);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("Could not retrieve Clients");
                        Debug.WriteLine("  Exception: " + ex.Message);
                        Debug.WriteLine("    Inner Exception: " + ex.InnerException);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Could Not Open Database");
                    Debug.WriteLine("  Exception: " + ex.Message);
                    Debug.WriteLine("    Inner Exception: " + ex.InnerException);
                }
                return Ok(listData);
            }

        }
        public IActionResult GetClientFromTestDbContext()
        {
            var getClient = _testDbContext.Clients.ToList();
            return Ok(getClient);
        }
        public IActionResult GetClientFromMainDbContextEfCore()
        {
            var getClient = _mainDbContext.Clients.ToList();
            return Ok(getClient);
        }
    }
```

**Note:** First method is demonstrating the ado.net example by using sqlClient. Rest of the method using entity framework core both your test and main db example.

Output:

[image]